# how to close a Screen without interrupting the program in Kivy

Tags: python, screen, kivy

I am beginner with respect to programming already resorted to previously forum which received help for simple issues.
I am currently looking for a way to close a screen without interrupting my program, I am using the "thread" to continue executing commands while the program is in the loop.

MAIN

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from time import sleep
import thread

class Display(Screen):
    myslider = ObjectProperty(None)

    def get_number(self):
        occupancy = format(self.myslider.value)
        print "value = ",occupancy

def display_screen():
    thread.start_new_thread(myApp().run, ())


def remove_screen():
    Screen.disabled()

def ring():
    sound = SoundLoader.load('ring.wav')
    if sound:
        sound.play()

class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Display()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ring()
    sleep(2)
    display_screen()
    sleep(7)
    remove_screen()
```

KV file

```
#:import random random.random

<Display>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    myslider: slider
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            source: 'data/images/background.jpg'
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 1, None
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        height: 44
        Image:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 24, 24
            source: 'data/logo/kivy-icon-24.png'
        Label:
            height: 24
            text_size: self.size
            color: (1, 1, 1, .8)
            text: 'Kivy 1.9.0.'
            valign: 'middle'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: 'Please enter \nthe number of occupants?'
            bold: True
            font_name: 'data/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'
            font_size: 22
            halign: 'center'

        Slider:
            id: slider
            min: 0.0
            max: 15.0
            value: 1.0
            step: 1.0
            orientation: "horizontal"
            width: "38dp"

        Label
            text: ''

        Label
            text: '{}'.format(slider.value)
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'top'
            bold: True
            text_size: self.size
            font_size: 18

    Button:
        text: 'Enter'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '50sp'
        on_release: root.get_number()
```

I left remove_screen function because it was what I found so far in my research. but not work.

Comment: Are you trying to make a normal kivy program? If so, don't mess with threading, just run myApp().run() and do everything in a normal kivy way with event bindings, properties etc.

Comment: In fact, what I want is to have a program with ready methods and a controller, the threading am using only test whether created methods are functioning as they should. Sorry for not being clear.